# $k(\mathfrak p)$ basis for $A / pA$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ramification

I'm reading [this pdf](http://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/math/MAT4250/h13/diskriminanten.pdf) which is showing that a rational prime $p$ ramifies if and only if it divides the discriminant of its number field $K$. I've come across the following line:

> Let $p \in \mathbb Z$ be a prime and let $a_1, \dots, a_n$ be a $\mathbb Z$ basis for $A$. Then of course $\overline{a_1}, \dots, \overline{a_n}$ is a $k(\mathfrak p)$ basis for $A/pA$.

Here $A$ is the ring of integers of $K$. My question: what does $k(\mathfrak p)$ mean, and why is this statement true?

Comment: It seems $k({\mathfrak p})$ means just ${\mathbb Z}/p{\mathbb Z}$ here - although the script does not introduce this notation. The statement is just tensoring the ${\mathbb Z}$-isomorphism ${\mathbb Z}^n \to A$ with ${\mathbb Z}/p{\mathbb Z}$.

Comment: Well, that makes life much easier :) Thanks!